# índice fuera de los límites de la matriz c#

Tags: c#

el siguiente codigo debe mostrar los datos de un archivo .dat a un datagridview y colocar en columnas. Pero muestra un error (índice fuera de los límites de la matriz).

Esta es la informacion del .dat

```
id         Fecha            Salida  

 1         2012-08-04       06:34:48
```

Codigo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\COMERCIAL\Desktop\1.dat", Encoding.UTF8);

        // SE GUARDA EL CONTENIDO DEL ARCHIVO EN UN ARREGLO DE STRING
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\COMERCIAL\Desktop\1.dat");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = (from l in lines
             let line = l.Split(new char[] { ' ' })
             select new
             {
               Id = line[0],
               FechaSalida = string.Format("{0{1}", line[1])
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Si tu archivo incluye líneas vacías, obviamente vas a tener un problema.

Comment: Me parece que en esta línea hay un detalle `FechaSalida = string.Format("{0{1}", line[1])` justamente con `{0{1}` la cadena no tiene el formato adecuado.

Comment: Por cierto, es bueno verte de nuevo @sstan :)

Comment: @Flxtr: .... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Podrias aplicar un filtro de linq que solo tome las lineas que pueden cortarse en al menos dos mitades

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = (from l in lines
             let line = l.Split(new char[] { ' ' })
             where line.Length > 1
             select new
             {
               Id = line[0],
               FechaSalida = string.Format("0{0}", line[1])
             }).ToList();
```

con el `where` podrias evitar el problema de acceder a una linea que no se divide.

Tambien valida como defines el `string.Format()` porque estas definiendo llaves de mas