# C# List<> El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección. Nombre del parámetro: index

Tags: c#, lista

necesito de su ayuda, estoy utilizando un list en mi capa de presentación, y estoy trayendo estos elementos de las de datos, en mi lista, los elementos los trae cuando ejecuto el compilador, y se muestra el dato en mi web. el escenario lo tengo asi;

los archivos de mi aplicación los tengo configurado en IIS, con la finalidad de no ejecutar el IIS Express que trae VS2017, solo compilo con F6 y actualizo mi explorador pero me sale

[image: imagen]

---

Aquí el código de la capa presentación,

```
/////capa presentacion//////
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using BBL;

namespace WEB
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected string BaseDatos;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //MostrarBaseDatos();
        }

        private void MostrarBaseDatos()
        {
            //  MostrarBaseDatos();
            BBLConected oBBLConected = null;
            oBBLConected = new BBLConected();

            List<string> Lista = new List<string>();

            Lista = oBBLConected.connectToSapBIAPI();

            BaseDatos = Lista[2].ToString();
        }

        protected void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
    }
}
////fin a capa presentacion///////

////capa logica de negocio/////
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DAL;

namespace BBL
{
    public class BBLConected
    {
        private Conection oConection = null;

        public List<string> connectToSapBIAPI()
        {
            oConection = new Conection();
            List<string> SapConnectParamteres = new List<string>();

            return SapConnectParamteres = oConection.connectToSapBIAPI();
        }
    }
}
//////fin capa logica de negocio//////
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu código donde te da el error? Creo que el indice que indicas es superior al indice máximo de tu lista.

Comment: Que tal victor, aqui el codigo

Comment: Por lo que se ve, la excepción te está diciendo que te sales del listado, intentas acceder a un objeto que es null. Poco más se puede decir sin ver tu código

Comment: Carlos, edita tu pregunta en vez de poner el código como respuesta. Para editarla tienes que pulsar "editar", justo bajo las etiquetas de tu pregunta.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [índice fuera de los límites de la matriz c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46977/%c3%adndice-fuera-de-los-l%c3%admites-de-la-matriz-c)

Comment: Una cosa que debes aprender es que por regla general es bueno checar por null antes de usar una variable de tipo referencia, y para acceso a índices, verificar antes si la lista o arreglo contiene suficientes elementos, algo así :if (Lista! = null && Lista. Count >= 3) BaseDatos = Lista[2].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Has usado break points?
Coloca uno en la línea:

```
return SapConnectParamteres =  oConection.connectToSapBIAPI();
```

Ese retorno está nulo o bien tiene menos de 3 items. Recuerda que las listas van de 0 al (largo - 1)

Comment: Claro que si, pude ver todos los envíos de parámetros de capa en capa de clase en clase y si funciona me devuelve el valor que necesito, indicando el indice de mi list, pero eso si funciona, cuando le doy ejecutar y compila ok y funciona de maravilla, el problema que tengo es cuando quiero ver la vista previa del desarrollo en mi IIS, (como si el aplicativo ya estuviera en producción) sin necesidad de dar ejecutar solo la tecla F6 para que compile todo backend y solo actualizar mi web de mis explorado para ver los cambios pero nada, me sale ese mensaje.

Comment: si lose, con los items no tengo problema al noser que necesariamente la aplicación deba estar ejecutada siempre para que estén disponibles los indices. la visualizaciones los hago desde el IIS y no desde IIS Express que trae VS2017 solo hago la compilacion de mi aplicacion y voy a mi IIS para ver el funcionamiento en si Fron y Back.

Comment: No será que ocupas ciertos permisos para ejecutar la línea? Porque no pruebas asociar el proceso del IIS al VS y usas el debug sobre el publicado?

Comment: Te refieres a que cuando le de ejecutar, se carge con el IIS local y no el express, te comento que la web lo hago por una api de SAP, que tiene sus objetos definidos cuando hago cnx con la base de datos. esto es raro porque cuando una aplicacion desarrollada dese 0, me carga en IIS local sin problemas se conecta con la BD automaticamente, en cambio con SAP no hace eso, solo cuando le doy ejecutar para visualizar el aplicativo.

Answer (score 0):

resolví mi problema, cuando crear la cadeno de conexion usando la DI API de sap, en la propiedad de "licenseSErver" debes cambiar el puerto 30000 por el 400000 ya que esto apunta al LSD via WEb y ya no al LSD para Escritorio, eso seria todo gracias por todo.